# Insert rows into table (second last) with ajax

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, document-body

I have a table with by default 25 rows, when i scroll at the bottom of the table i want to insert 25 more rows etc... everything is working correctly, but in a specific table i want to keep the last row of the first 25 rows and put the 25 next before it.

Ex :

```
<table id="maintable" name="maintable">
<tr>
    <td id="row 1"></td>
    <td id="row 2"></td>
    <td id="row 3"></td>
    <td id="row 4"></td>
    ....
    <td id="row 24"></td>
    <td id="row 25"></td>
</tr>
</table>
```

After scrolling i want to have:

```
<table id="maintable" name="maintable">
<tr>
    <td id="row 1"></td>
    ...
    <td id="row 24"></td>
    <td id="row 26"></td>
    <td id="row 27"></td>
    ...
    <td id="row 48"></td>
    <td id="row 49"></td>
    <td id="row 50"></td>
    <td id="row 25"></td>
</tr>
</table>
```

So i just want to keep this "row 25" at the bottom of the table

So i am trying to do the ajax with

```
function ScrollLoader(){
    $.ajax({
        url: '../myScrollLoader/scroll.inc.php',
        type: 'POST',
        data: $('#formScrollLoader').serialize(),
        success: function(result) {
                $("#maintable tbody>tr:last").prev("tr").append(result);
                $(window).data('ajaxready', true);
            }
        }
    });
}
```

It barely works but the 25 "next" are adding Inside the last TD of the 24 row and not After him (I'm not sure if i'm totaly clear with my english)

Comment: There is too many code that doesn't really matter for my problem... But i can try to edit my post to make it clearer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use before()

```
       $('#maintable tbody tr>:last').before(result);
```

The [**FIDDLE DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/nMhmS/629/) will help you

Comment: Ah ! Amazing, just what i needed ! I was trying to add "after the 24 rows" but i had to add it before the 25, your logic is better than mine ! Thanks you !